# SQL - Update table

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need to update a table and this is my sql code so far but i'm getting the following error message:

***Line 30: Incorrect syntax near ')'.***

```
UPDATE dbo.Part
SET SupplierShortName = NationalSupplier.ShortName,
SupplierLongName = NationalSupplier.LongName
SELECT    *
  FROM    dbo.Part
 JOIN    dbo.NationalSupplier
    ON    Part.SupplierNumber    =    NationalSupplier.Number
   AND (ISNULL(Part.SupplierShortName,'') <> ISNULL(NationalSupplier.ShortName,'') 
    OR ISNULL(Part.SupplierLongName,'') <> ISNULL(NationalSupplier.LongName,''))
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.NationalPart
    ON Part.NationalPartID = NationalPart.NationalPartID
WHERE Part.DWCreationEntityID = 1
   AND NationalPart.NationalPartID is NULL


Thanks in advance for any valuable tips !
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE dbo.Part
SET SupplierShortName = NationalSupplier.ShortName,
SupplierLongName = NationalSupplier.LongName
  FROM    dbo.Part
 JOIN    dbo.NationalSupplier
    ON    Part.SupplierNumber    =    NationalSupplier.Number
   AND (ISNULL(Part.SupplierShortName,'') <> ISNULL(NationalSupplier.ShortName,'') 
    OR ISNULL(Part.SupplierLongName,'') <> ISNULL(NationalSupplier.LongName,''))
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.NationalPart
    ON Part.NationalPartID = NationalPart.NationalPartID
WHERE Part.DWCreationEntityID = 1
   AND NationalPart.NationalPartID is NULL
```

You should alias the table names to make things concise.